# Simplifying js for a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pretty basic code html code for a dropdown, as can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awre147/g9zyd/1/) it works, but is there a way to simplify this js code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var n = ".dropdown-menu", no = 'drop';

  $('.dropdown').click(function () {               
     if($(n).hasClass(no)) {                       
        $(n).removeClass(no);                      
     } else {
        $(n).addClass(no);                        
     }
   }).mouseover(function() {          
        $(n).addClass(no);                         
   }).mouseout(function() {                        
        if($(n).mouseover()){        
          $(n).removeClass(no);  
        }           
   })


});
```

please note that I am aware that I can go **css only** by adding just one line.. so that isn't the question.

```
 #navigation-top #navigation-holder li:hover > ul {
     display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use toggleClass instead of add/remove class.
In the below code we can remove the if check and directly call removeClass

```
if ($(n).mouseover()) { 
    $(n).removeClass(no);
}
```

So the final optimized code like this:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function () {
    $(n).toggleClass(no);
}).mouseover(function () {
    $(n).addClass(no);
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(n).removeClass(no);
})
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9zyd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.dropdown').click(function () {               
     $(n).toggleClass(no);
}).hover(
   function() {
      $(n).addClass(no);
   }, function() {
      $(n).removeClass(no);
   }
);
```

Not tested, but that should do what you're looking for.

Refs:

https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, use [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to optimize the class switching

As well as the use of [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to replace mouseover & mouseout events.

Therefore your code will turn out this way:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function () {
    $(n).toggleClass(no);
}).hover(
function () {
    $(n).addClass(no);
}
,function () {
        $(n).removeClass(no);
}
);
```

JS Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/g9zyd/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggleClass method from jQuery library, and some little trick to do your task!

```
function rp(el){
  $(n).toggleClass(no, el.data);
}
var n = ".dropdown-menu",
    no = 'drop';
$('.dropdown').click(rp).mouseover(true, rp).mouseout(false, rp);
```

Try [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9zyd/6/)